# How to get pid by unique process name in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I have two java program running on server `MyProgram` and `MyProgramTest`.

```
ps -ef | grep -i java

root       505 17711  0 16:54 pts/4    00:00:00 grep -i MyProgram
root     16450 16448 99 16:46 pts/4    00:07:29 java MyProgram
root     16473 16471 99 16:46 pts/4    00:07:29 java MyProgramTest
```

I want to search there pid using below commands

```
ps ax | grep -v grep | grep MyProgram
```

It should give me PID 16450 but it is giving both

```
16450 pts/4    Sl     9:19 java MyProgram
16473 pts/4    Sl     9:19 java MyProgramTest
```

Expected Output :

```
16450 pts/4    Sl     9:19 java MyProgram
```

How to get PID by Unique Process Name in linux ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206910) answer.

Comment: How about `grep -w` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -w "MyProgram"
```

or

```
ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "\MyProgram\b"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -w  MyProgram
```

-w for Whole Word Match. However, It will also match things like MyProgram or MyProgram Hello.

Comment: As MyProgram is java process so is there any option to search MyProgram process as java type?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid tricks like `grep -v grep` it is better to use `pgrep`:

```
pgrep --exact MyProgram
```

Comment: That's strange, this option should be present in recent linux. See [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

Suffix $, ie; the process name ends with "MyProgram",

```
$ ps -ef |grep MyProgram$
```